# Is there a way to install all python modules at once using pip?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, pip

I would like to install all available modules for Python 2.7.12 using a single pip command. Is there a way to do this without having to specify every single package name?

Comment: Why would you want that? Seems horrendously superfluous to me.

Comment: @rsnaveen: what does "all available modules" means for you? You can install from a requirement file: `pip install -r requirements.txt`. You can also list all installed packages and put it in a requirement file: `pip freeze > requirement.txt`.

Comment: `pip install ...` can't possibly inst*all* *all* possible packages, except you have a predefined list of packages

Comment: @SimonKlaver I am working on this new project that might want me to install different modules at different times and I don't know right now what modules I might need. So I just want to install every module out there so that I don't have to install them when I actually have to use them.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye So there is no way to auto-install modules without specifying package names?

Comment: You could parse the results of `pip search *` and install all those with `pip install` but... I don't really recommend this approach.

Comment: There are tens of thousands of packages. You can't possibly install them all.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE For example, I came across an example that used 'statistics' module and when I tried to run the code I obviously got an error since I haven't previously installed it. I was just wondering if I could install all modules at once using the pip command.

Comment: @DanielRoseman gotta install em all?

Comment: @rsnaveen: Hum! `statistics` is a built-in module in Python2 and 3. You don't need to install it! There is a confusion between "module" (or "package") and "library". With `pip` you can install Python libraries. You can't install modules/packages.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I believe you mean that you [install python modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/#basic-usage)

Comment: @Wayne Werner: well, with `pip`, you install Python libraries, which is more than simply modules ("foo.py" file) or packages ("bar/" directory + "__init__.py"). Libraries can also contains extra data (resource files), etc. The thing you install is a library; the result of the installation is *Python* modules and/or packages + extra resources).

Answer (score 34):

I highly recommend against doing this - the overwhelmingly supported best practice is to use a requirements.txt file, listing the packages you want to install specifically.

You then install it with `pip install -r requirements.txt` and it installs all the packages for your project.

This has several benefits:

- Repeatability by installing only the required packages
- Conciseness

However, if you really *do* want to install ALL python packages (note that there are *thousands*), you can do so via the following:

> pip search * | grep ")[[:space:]]" | cut -f1 -d" "

I strongly recommend against this as it's likely to do horrible things to your system, as it will attempt to install *every python package* (and why it's in spoiler tags).

Comment: I say do it. Don't let your dreams be dreams.

Comment: @enderland I got the following error

'grep : The term 'grep' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:16
+ pip search * | grep ")[[:space:]]" | cut -f1 -d" "
+                ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (grep:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException'

Comment: I guess grep doesn't work under Windows (for obvious reasons). By the way, as you are using Windows, why did you also tag Ubuntu @rsnaveen?

Comment: @SimonKlaver I use both Windows and Ubuntu. I tagged them both for exactly this reason. Finding a command that works only in windows or ubuntu.

Comment: Well, this answer probably works in Ubuntu. Definitely does not work in Windows, as `grep` does not exist there.

Comment: @SimonKlaver it may be over a decade out of date, but it still works fine: [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @enderland The command you provided only lists all the modules available and doesn't install them. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is a terrible idea, but you could always use [autoinstaller](https://github.com/mdipierro/autoinstaller), which will automatically download packages via `pip` if you don't have them installed.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** The other answers *were* right when they said that this was a terrible idea: Some of the packages I have installed using this method will not work because their fixed-old required dependencies have been updated by other packages. Next time, I'm using virtualenv. Some day, I'm going to produce a list of packages from packages.pypy.org with their dependencies, so that someone can make many environments with those packages quickly.

---

Well, I did find a way to do this, but only for the 1000 most popular packages at http://packages.pypy.org. But other pages can be processed too, it just needs some creativity. For that page you will need a spreadsheet program to process tha page. I used LibreOffice Calc. And I did do this on windows using the Command Prompt.

First, open the link I just posted and select/copy all the text (and do not expand any of the package names on the webpage).

Then, paste it on any cell in Calc. Open the Find & Replace dialog. If you use another spreadsheet program, make sure it's Find & Replace supports regexps. Select the checkbox next to `Regular Expressions` (or something like that), type `downloads:\s+\d+` in the `Search for` field, make sure there is no text in the `Replace with` field, and leave all the other options at their defaults, click `Replace all` (assuming the program has this button). After that, you get rid of the trailing spaces by doing another replace with a space in the `Search for` field (Python package names do not have spaces). Once you do these two replaces, you have a package name in each cell.

Then you copy the entire spreadsheet into a text editor, any editor should work (I used Notepad). The text editor will put the contents of each cell (i.e. the package names) onto it's own line. There won't be any blank lines in the file (but it doesn't hurt to check). At this point you can close the spreadsheet, you don't have to save it's data.

Now save the text file. Open a command prompt and change to the folder where you saved the text file. Now type:

```
for /F %p in ('type TEXT_FILE_NAME.txt') DO pip.exe install %p
```

[If Command Prompt can't find the right pip to use, then you need to type the full path to pip e.g. C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe]

Voila, pip is now installing all of the packages listed on the link I gave.

You should redirect stdout (and maybe stderr too) to a file because command prompts don't have a large history buffer. For that, you put something like this at the end of the command:

```
>>PIP_STDOUT_FILE.txt 2>>PIP_STDERR_FILE.txt
```

Be careful about abruptly interrupting pip if you use this, because output no longer goes to the terminal. You might kill it in the middle of a package installation. In particular, if you use a text editor to view the output, reload the file frequently. It's safer to append `--log LOG_FILE.txt` instead of the above, but the log file becomes more verbose and also writes its messages to the command prompt as usual.

There are quite a number of

1. Linux-only packages
2. Packages built with a Microsoft C++ compiler

and using pip to install these will fail unless you do some additional work. But this should work for the majority of packages.