# How to install all the pip packages for python in one run?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation, pip

I want to install the python packages for 3.6. There is a n number of packages that i want to install. My question is how to install all the packages in one click.

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962947/is-there-a-way-to-install-all-python-modules-at-once-using-pip

Comment: @Sam you _need_ close rights ASAP (work on it now:)) as your link was very useful (I already knew it but still...). Next time you can comment like "possible/exact duplicate of <your link>)" even if you don't have close privileges.

Comment: Thanks for appreciating @Jean-FrançoisFabre , I am new to stackoverflow. I am still getting used to it. Learning new features daily. Hope I'll get that right soon.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file `requirements.txt` which package names and their version number:

```
Django==1.3
PyYAML==3.09
```

And then install packages from it:

```
pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt
```

Or, you can provide multiple package names in one go:

```
pip install django==1.3 pyyaml==3.09
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux (and I'm sure windows will be the same), you can just list all the packages that you want to install.

I did a quick test just to show you:

```
root@myserver-cent:~ # pip install zerodoc  var_dump pyradiodns
Collecting zerodoc
  Downloading zerodoc-0.2.3.tar.gz
Collecting var_dump
  Downloading var_dump-1.1.tar.gz
Collecting pyradiodns
  Downloading pyradiodns-0.1.tar.gz
Collecting dnspython (from pyradiodns)
  Downloading dnspython-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (177kB)
```

Comment: very nice. Maybe this answer will fit better in the "original" question (because this technique isn't shown there). Can you move it there (and delete this one + ping me so I can "move" my vote) ?

Comment: Well, as I see it, the "original" question was more about "... having to specify every single package name?". So my answer would not "fit" there.